# hidden property not reflecting immediately in angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to hide a div on condition, so I used hidden property like

```
<div [hidden]="isControlDisplayed()?false:true">
```

isControlDisplayed() method returns true/false based on some other dropdown(select) control in the form group .  so when this method returns false it doesn't reflect immediately , it reflects only after I click somewhere else on window.

I have one observation like angular calls method only on some actions on window , is it something like this. how can I solve this issue. can somebody help me.

Thank you

Comment: can you show your `.ts` component, and are you using ChangeDetection OnPush?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*ngIf` directive.

```
<div *ngIf="isControlDisplayed();">
```

Comment: I think this is the correct syntax: <div ng-if="isControlDisplayed();">

Comment: @GeraldLeRoy `ng-if` is angularJS's syntax.

Comment: actually the problem is when we use *ngIf that div is not displayed in the DOM and am applying one directive on that div , so that div is not able to listen to the events. that is why i used [hidden] property

Comment: @pbhle Your problem is that in the end, div is hidden, but not immediately when `isControlDisplayed()` return `false`. Is it correct?